# Как получить данные определенного тега OPC при помощи python?

Tags: python, opc

Передо мной встала задача получить данные с OPC-сервера.
На машине установлен **python 3.7**, либу скачивал с **гита** разработчика **mkwiatkowski**
Я подключил библиотеку OpenOPC. Я могу получить список item, но как обратиться к конкретному значению прибора я не знаю. 
Вот дерево моего ОРС-сервера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делал запрос как показано на картинке ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На официальном сайте OpenOPC есть пример кода обращения к тегу

```
opc.read('Random.Int4')
(19169, 'Good', '06/24/07 15:56:11')
```

Мне не понятно откуда откуда взялось .Int4
Главный мой вопрос состоит в том, как мне обратиться и считать значение например с 
*'COM4.TRM_210(adr=32)Ср_р-р, 2 зона.Оперативные параметры прибора.Тнэ Зона 2'*
(Тнэ Зона 2 - это уже само значение).
Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помогли коллеги с другого форума.
Ответ на мой вопрос:

```
import OpenOPC

tagsValue = [];
tagsValue.append(opc.list('COM4.TRM_202(adr=104)T_слой_Ср_р-ра.Оперативные параметры')[3])
opc = OpenOPC.client()
servers = opc.servers()
print(servers)
try:
    opc.connect(servers[0])
except:
    print("не удалось подключиться к ОРС - серверу")
val = opc.read(tagsValue, update=1, include_error=True)
print(val)
opc.close()
```

Надеюсь кому-нибудь помогу этим.

Answer (score 0):

Очень важная поправка, это всё работает на 32-разрядной версии Python. Два дня мучился искал ошибку, пока не установил python для 32-битных систем.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что это всё на 64-битах не будет работать?

Comment: Предполагаю из-за библиотеки PyWin32. Изначально использовал в проекте Python 3.7.3 MSC v.1916 64 bit - программа не работала, выкидывала ошибку работы с памятью. Запускал и на версии 3.10, но тоже 64 bit была таже самая ошибка. Установил Python 3.8.1 MSC v.1916 32 bit - всё заработало, говорю же пару дней поиска неисправностей и только потом понял проблему.